# Probable timing issue on populating array from API

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to fill an array with arrays of strings (urls), that I get from API.

The type of the array is:

```
var secImageUrls = [[String]](())
```

However, I think I'm having some sort of timing issue while populating the array, because it looks different every time, even though it should all be the same.

Here's the code:

```
var usersN = 0

for user in usersArray {
    usersN++

    let collab = user as! String
    let r = i
    let p = usersN

    Alamofire.request(.GET, Constants.Path.rootUrl + "/api/users/?username=" + 
                            collab +  "&fields=image", headers: self.headers)
        .responseJSON {response in

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
                let singleImgArray = response.result.value?.objectAtIndex(0) as! NSDictionary
                let imageUrl = singleImgArray.objectForKey("image") as! String

                self.collabsArray.append(imageUrl)
            }

            if p == usersArray.count {
                //TO REMOVE???
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
                    self.secImageUrls.append(self.collabsArray)
                    self.collabsArray = []
                }
            }

            if r == self.jsonFeeds.count {
                self.loadingStatus = "collabsPics"
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
    }
}
```

EDIT: This is the whole method now, using dispatch groups. However, I still have problems with the array(Don't mind about the missing else statement):

```
    var i = 0

    for feed in jsonFeeds {


        i++

        let feedType = feed["type"] as! Int

        if feedType == 1 {


            let usersArray : NSArray = feed["users"] as! NSArray


            let group = dispatch_group_create()


            for user in usersArray {


                let collab = user as! String

                let r = i



                dispatch_group_enter(group)

                Alamofire.request(.GET, Constants.Path.rootUrl + "/api/users/?username=" + collab +  "&fields=image", headers: self.headers)
                    .responseJSON {response in


                        let singleImgArray = response.result.value?.objectAtIndex(0) as! NSDictionary

                        let imageUrl = singleImgArray.objectForKey("image") as! String

                        self.collabsArray.append(imageUrl)

                        dispatch_group_leave(group)

                }

                dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.secImageUrls.append(self.collabsArray)
                    self.collabsArray = []
                    if r == self.jsonFeeds.count {

                        self.loadingStatus = "collabsPics"
                        print(self.secImageUrls)
                        self.tableView.reloadData()


                    }

                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Since you're executing a network operation with an indeterminate time, the urls appended to `secImageUrls` will be indeterminate as well.  It's also not clear why you're dispatching to the main queue (and why you're doing it twice not just once)  And then the one thing that probably ought to be relegated to the main queue (`self.tableView.reloadData()`) isn't...

Comment: You have redundant `()` in array initialization - `[[String]]()`. Also why do you process response in async blocks?

Comment: @mixel in what way is the `()` redundant? Without it the code does not work.

Comment: @luk2302 I mean that `[[String]]()` instead of `[[String]](())` also works.

Comment: @mixel Ah, I see, sorry!

Comment: I edited the question with the new code guys @luk2302

Comment: I edited the question with the new code guys @mixel

Answer (score 1):

You *kind of* have a timing issue.

You start a few requests in order - you loop over some data and execute an asynchronous request for each data point.

As soon as the request finishes you append some data to an array. So far so good.

**BUT** nobody says that the requests have to be finished in the order they started. The order in which they finish is pretty much random. One request can be more expensive to compute, take longer to send the data over the network etc.

You therefore either have to deal with the fact that your order is not deterministic or implement some logic / ordering for it. Based on the userIf or name or something - your decision.

Comment: @dpstart have I said anything about dispatch groups? No! Because I do not like them, you have to sort the array as I said.

Answer (score 0):

As my comment and @luk2302's answer indicate, the basic problem is that you're relying on network operations to finish in a dependable order.  My approach would be to create an array of the expected results, fire off all the requests, populating the array as the respond, and then reload the table when done.  Wrap it all with a dispatch_group for coordination, and it looks something like

```
var collabsArray = Array<String?>(count: usersArray.count, repeatedValue: nil)

// Create a dispatch group for coordination
let group = dispatch_group_create()

for userIndex in 0..<usersArray.count {
    let user = usersArray[userIndex]
    let collab = user as! String

    // "Enter" the group, basically increments the count of operations in the group
    dispatch_group_enter(group)

    Alamofire.request(.GET, Constants.Path.rootUrl + "/api/users/?username=" + collab +  "&fields=image", headers: self.headers)
        .responseJSON {response in
            let singleImgArray = response.result.value?.objectAtIndex(0) as! NSDictionary
            let imageUrl = singleImgArray.objectForKey("image") as! String

            collabsArray[userIndex] = imageUrl

            // "leave" the group, basically decrements the count of operations in the group           
            dispatch_group_leave(group)
    }
}

// Schedule a block to execute when all the "enter" calls have been matched
// with "leave", ie., when all the network operations have finished, the block
// will be executed on the requested queue (in this case the main queue) so
// we don't have to futz with dispatch_async
dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    secImageUrls.append(collabsArray)
    self.loadingStatus = "collabsPics"
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you just explain me the queues logic in this example?

Comment: Really, for something like this I'd refactor the work flow so that the table cells loaded the images and redisplayed themselves as needed so that individual cells refreshed as data became available, but that's an entirely different question and answer.

Comment: Are you asking about dispatch_group_*?

Comment: That would be part of the "something like"  It's not particularly clear what you're actually trying to accomplish :)  Looking at it again, I may be using secImageUrls where you're using collab?  In which case you can replace all the secImageUrls with collab and then in the _notify call append to secImageUrls.

Comment: Yes exactly. Anyway, I'm trying to build a mega array (secImageUrls) storing the urls for several images on each cell of a table view.

Comment: Oops, make that collabsArray, not collab.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96179/discussion-between-dpstart-and-david-berry).